# Docker in Docker (via Deamon socket) cannot mount host volume

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I am running a windows host and starting a linux container. Inside that linux container I want to be able to start other docker containers on the windows host.
As I bind mount the docker deamon when starting my first linux container(according to this article: https://itnext.io/docker-in-docker-521958d34efd) with the following command:

```
docker run -it --rm --name rqd07 --network=opencue-master_default -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --volume F:/:/testVOLUME opencue/rqd
```

after installing docker inside the container I want to execute the following:

```
docker run -it --rm -v F:/OPENCUE/debug_renderscripts/nuke/ABC_0000:/render nuke:12.0v2 nuke -t -F 1-10 -X Write1 /render/ABC_0000.nk
```

> docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mode: /render

so there seems to be a problem with mounting the windows volume. However, I thought the that docker deamon of the host just receives the command via the socket. The command executes correctly when run directly from the host os. Removing the volume mount when running from inside the container, works as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`F:/OPENCUE/debug_renderscripts/nuke/ABC_0000:/render`

The windows path contains two colons, so docker tries to use render like one would use `read`, `write` modes, etc...

Have a read of this:
https://mattcbaker.com/posts/mounting-window-dir-docker/